# Looking for a recommendation on a solid graph DB

Tags: database, graphs

I'd like your opinion/recommendation on a solid graph DB.
I'm currently doing a POC incorporating a graph DB to a commercial product with graph like data.

Here are the requirements:
The load on the system is ~2M nodes and ~50M edges.
The main usages are graph traversals (specialized BFS/DFS) and speed is important.
I'd like a solid (=reliable) product.
Graph distribution is not important but replication for a HA cluster is.
Commercial or Free solutions are both ok.

Here is what I tried so far:
A couple of years ago I had some experience with OrientDB for a different project but found it buggy. Reading current forums, it seems that this is still the case.

I currently tried Neo4J as it is the most popular graph DB and I really liked it's cypher query language, but got into difficulties importing my existing DB (unreasonably long import times, unexpected server crashes without any notification or logs) and couldn't resolve it using the forums.

I thought I'd try ArangoDB next?
Can you think/recommend on a good graph DB.

Thanks,